When capturing the return value of Invoke-Command I don't see the output of the commands
In a PowerShell script, I have something like this:
$Session = New-PSSession -ComputerName "WSEM00G2NZ" -Credential $credObject
Invoke-Command -Session $Session -Scriptblock {
    python path\to\script\print_stuff.py
}
Remove-PSSession -Session $Session

I.e. it runs a python script on a remote machine. Running the script, I can see the output from the python script. Now, I would like to capture a return value, but if I change the PowerShell script to the following, I don't see the output of the python script anymore.
$Session = New-PSSession -ComputerName "WSEM00G2NZ" -Credential $credObject
$returnedValue = Invoke-Command -Session $Session -Scriptblock {
    python path\to\script\print_stuff.py
}
Remove-PSSession -Session $Session

Why is this, and how can I both capture a return value, and have the output from the python script be visible on screen?

Have you tried simply running Write-Output $returnedValue afterwards?

Ok, I didn't realize that the python output would count as return value... :) Still, is it possible to get it to print the output when it is running, instead of printing everything after Invoke-Command has finished?

Yes, anything outputted is just sent to standard output which defaults to the screen, so having $returnedValue = tells it to send it to that variable instead. If you're not using the $returnedValue elsewhere later you could just remove that from your code so the output is handled "normally" instead.

Use the -OutVariable common parameter to store the output from Invoke-Command in a variable while still sending it downstream:
Invoke-Command -Session $Session -Scriptblock {
    python path\to\script\print_stuff.py
} -OutVariable returnValue

Now you'll get the output on screen as it's sent and have a copy stored in $returnValue
